# finding the length of three words

Tags: javascript

I have a function that has three words, I want to return the minimal length of these three words.
I solved with `Math.min()` method, but I tried to solve it with `reduce()` , but it didn't work.
this is my code

```
    const words = (w1, w2, w3) => {
      return Math.min(w1.length, w2.length, w3.length)
    }

 let output = words('hi', 'hello', 'good') 
 console.log(output) // --> 2
```

so what I'm trying to do is to make it work with `reduce`
this is what I tried with `reduce`

```js
const words = (w1, w2, w3) => {
 let ar = [w1, w2, w3]
 ar.reduce((a,i) => i.length < a.length ? i.length : a.length)
}
```

Any help it would be so very appreciated.

Comment: You’re not returning the result of reduce.

Comment: You'll also need to initialize `reduce` using the second parameter, probably to `Infinity` and only call `.length` on `i` (which should be named `elem` since `i` means index). Beyond that, `reduce` is an inappropriate way to do it anyway...`const shortest = (...args) => Math.min(...args.map(e => e.length))`? `words` is not a very good function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with reduce, you can do it like this:

```js
const words = (w1,w2,w3) =>  
  [w1,w2,w3].reduce((smallest,word) => word.length < smallest ? word.length : smallest, Infinity)

console.log(words( "hi", "there", "how"))
```

a big help is naming things in your reduce so you don't mistake things for what they aren't (in your case you mistook `a` for a word rather than a number )

Comment: Hi @Keith Nicholas, your code is awesome, but I got it as a test so I cant change the paramas

Comment: @Th1  changed to keep the signature the same :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the reduce example in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). The accumulator is the result of the first iteration. With that in mind, change your reducer to return the smaller of the two strings.

```js
const words = (w1, w2, w3) => {
    let ar = [w1, w2, w3];
    const reducer = (a, i) => a.length < i.length ? a : i;
    return ar.reduce(reducer).length;
}

const output = words('hi', 'hello', 'good');
console.log(output) // --> 2
```

If you want it in one line, it would look like this:

```js
const words = (w1, w2, w3) => [w1, w2, w3].reduce((a, i) => a.length < i.length ? a : i).length;

const output = words('hi', 'hello', 'good');
console.log(output) // --> 2
```

Comment: Thank you @Russ Van Bert, i was thinking to make the code kind of short ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need return result after reduce and return inside reduce as

```
const words = (w1, w2, w3) => {
 let ar = [w1, w2, w3]
 return ar.reduce((a,i) => {
   debugger;
   if(i.length > a) {
     return i.length;
   }else{
     return ar[0].length;
   }
 }, ar[0].length)
}
```

```js
const words = (w1, w2, w3) => {
 let ar = [w1, w2, w3]
 return ar.reduce((a,i) => {
   debugger;
   if(i.length > a) {
     return i.length;
   }else{
     return ar[0].length;
   }
 }, ar[0].length)
}

let output = words('hi', 'hello', 'good') 
 console.log(output) // --> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is totally works
Thank you so much @Hien Nguyen

```js
const words = (w1, w2, w3) => {
 let ar = [w1, w2, w3]
  return ar.reduce((a, i) => i.length < a ? i.length : ar[0].length)
}

 let output = words('hi', 'hello', 'good') 
 console.log(output) // --> 2
```